# adding object to collection

Tags: c#

My roster object has the following property:

```
    [DataMember]
    public ObservableCollection<personDetail> personContact
    {
        get
        {
            return _personContact;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _personContact)
            {
                _personContact = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("personContact");
            }
        }
    }
```

personDetail contains:

```
    private string _name;
    private string _phone;
    private string _email;
```

and the get and set statements as well.

I'm trying to add the personDetail to my personContact property...

I've tried the following:

```
            roster myRoster;
            myRoster = roster.CreateNewRoster();

                personDetail myPerson;
                myPerson = personDetail.newPerson();

                myPerson.name = ph.tbNameValue.Text.ToString();
                myPerson.phone = ph.tbPhoneValue.Text.ToString();
                myPerson.email = "None Yet";

            myRoster.personContact.Add(myPerson);
```

**as well as:**

```
myRoster.personContact.Add(new personDetail() {name = myPerson.name, phone = myPerson.email});
```

Each time I'm getting a NullReferenceException when ever I try to add myPerson to personContact...

I'm probably doing something dumb...  Can you identify what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thanks and Happy New Year!

Comment: Where do you getting exception, did you debug it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That suggests nothing's setting `personContact` to an empty `ObservableCollection<personDetail>` to start with. I suggest that `CreateNewRoster()` should probably do that before returning it. Otherwise, do it yourself:

```
myRoster.personContact = new ObservableCollection<personDetail>();
```

As an aside, you should really try to follow the .NET naming conventions, where public types and properties are named with PascalCase, leading to type names of `PersonDetail` and `Roster`, as well as property names of `Name`, `Phone`, `Email` and `PersonContact`. I'd also rename `PersonContact` to something which sounds more understandable - possibly just `Contacts`?

Comment: Thank you as always for this info...  Do you have a resource that I can read about the naming conventions?  I'm sure there is something in MSDN but if you have a link that would be great.

Comment: @Jeff: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/xzf533w0.aspx - there may be an updated version, but that should be a fine starting point.

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize `Roster.personContact` to something - an empty list for example:

```
myRoster.personContact = new ObservableCollection<personDetail>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have never assigned anything to `myRoster.personContact` so it is still `null`.

I'd also suggest that you follow the Microsoft [Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0.aspx).

Comment: I think `personDetail.newPerson();` is static method and is factory

Answer (score 1):

Does `myRoster = roster.CreateNewRoster();` instanciate _personContact
Otherwise it seems that it is null and then you call add on a null object.